# Symfony 2 googleleads namespace issue

Tags: php, symfony, google-ads-api

I try to integrate a the googleleads php libary into Symfony 2.8 lts.
I need the totalConvValue out of my Adwords campain.
I put my method into a symfony service. The script is working until
I want to generate the report itself.
when I call \ReportsUtils it says.
For the ReportUtils::DownloadReport exist multible definitions.
I get an error message:
**Attempted to load class "ReportUtils" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?
500 Internal Server Error - ClassNotFoundException**

```
    $clientId = '';
    $clientSecret = '';
    $refreshToken = '';
    $developerToken = '';
    $userAgent = 'k';
    $clientCustomerID = '6';
    $adwords_version ='';
    $adGroupId = '';
    $days = '30';
    $keyword_id = '';

    // Enter parameters required by the code example.
    $campaignId = '';

    $oauth2Info = [
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'refresh_token' => $refreshToken,

    ];

    // See AdWordsUser constructor
    $user = new \AdWordsUser();

    if (1 == 1) {
        $user->SetDeveloperToken($developerToken);
    }

    $user->SetUserAgent($userAgent);
    $user->SetOAuth2Info($oauth2Info);
    $user->SetClientCustomerId($clientCustomerID);
    $user->SetUserAgent($userAgent);

    //$reportDefinitionService = $user->GetService('ReportDefinitionService');

    // Load the service, so that the required classes are available.
    // $user->LoadService('ReportDefinitionService', $adwords_version);

    // Get the service, which loads the required classes.

    $user->GetService('AdGroupCriterionService', $adwords_version);


    // Create selector.
    $selector = new \Selector();
    $selector->fields = array('KeywordText', 'Id', 'TotalConvValue');

    // Filter out deleted criteria.
    //$selector->predicates[] = new Predicate('Status', 'NOT_IN', array('DELETED'));
    $selector->predicates[] = new \Predicate('Id', 'IN', array($keyword_id));



    $dateRange = new \DateRange();

    $str1 = '-1 days';
    $str2 = '-1 days';
    if($days > 0)
    {
        $str1 = '-'.$days.' days';
        $str2 = '-'.$days.' days';
    }
    $dateRange->min = date('Ymd', strtotime($str1));
    $dateRange->max = date('Ymd', strtotime($str2));
    $selector->dateRange = $dateRange;


    // Create report definition.
    $reportDefinition = $user->GetService('ReportDefinitionService');

    // $user->GetService('CampaignService');

    $reportDefinition->selector = $selector;
    $reportDefinition->reportName = 'Criteria performance report #' . \uniqid();
    $reportDefinition->dateRangeType = 'CUSTOM_DATE';
    $reportDefinition->reportType = 'KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT';
    $reportDefinition->downloadFormat = 'XML';

    // Exclude criteria that haven't recieved any impressions over the date range.
    $reportDefinition->includeZeroImpressions = FALSE;

    // Set additional options.
    $options = array('version' => $adwords_version, 'returnMoneyInMicros' => FALSE);


    // Create Report




    \ReportUtils::DownloadReport($reportDefinition, $filePath, $user, $options);
```

Comment: I suspect you didn't really want to post your actual clientId on a public board.  Might want to edit a bit.

Comment: And ReportsUtils is depreciated which explains why the class cannot be found.  Need to use ReportDownloader.  Follow the docs.

Comment: Thanks, but its anyway just a test adwords account.

Comment: I still found the ReportsUtils in the newest branch. https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/src/Google/Api/Ads/AdWords/Util/v201509/ReportUtils.php. Is it really deprecated?

Comment: Ok I found the deprication statement within the method. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Still it does not expain my error message. The class is deprecated but I should get a decrecation message. Its still not loading..

Comment: Nope.  Check the source code.  TheReportsUtil class itself has been moved into a legacy directory.  It's no longer possible for php to find it unless you mess with the autoload directories which could have unpleasant consequences.

Comment: I used the ReportDownloader class instead of the ReportsUtils now but I still get the same error 'Attempted to load class "ReportDownloader" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?'

Comment: Update your question.  I suspect you forgot the back slash.

Comment: '
        \ReportDownloader::downloadReport($exportFormat, $filePath = null);
        // \ReportUtils::DownloadReport($reportDefinition, $filePath, $user, $options);

        die;'

Comment: No I used the Backslash

Comment: Ok I solved it. I put inside the constructor an include statement to the class. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Glad it is working but you should not need an include statement.